# How does Nested Array work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Nested Array in JavaScript is defined as Array (Outer array) within another array (inner array). An Array can have one or more inner Arrays. These nested array (inner arrays) are under the scope of outer array means  can i access these inner array elements based on outer array name?

```
const favMovies = [
    'Begin Again', 'Soul',
    ['Matrix', 'Matix Reloaded', 'Matrix Revolutions'],
    ['Frozen', 'Frozen 2',
        ['Tangled', 'Alladin']
    ]
]
```

can i access these inner array elements based on outer array name with favMovies?

Comment: Yes; to get the 2nd element of the first inner array, it'd be `favMovies[2][1]`.

Comment: Is it possible to find the index number if there is a large array?

Comment: Can you add some detail of what you need to do with favMovies? Search if it contains some value, add/remove items, display all favMovies in page etc.

Comment: I Want to display all favMovies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive function for find all elements.

Like this:

```js
   const favMovies = [
    'Begin Again', 'Soul',
    ['Matrix', 'Matix Reloaded', 'Matrix Revolutions'],
    ['Frozen', 'Frozen 2',
        ['Tangled', 'Alladin']
    ]
   ];

   function recursive_for(arr){
      for(var key in arr){
         if(arr[key] instanceof Array){
            recursive_for(arr[key]);
         }else{
            console.log(arr[key]);
         }
      }
   }

   recursive_for(favMovies);
```